# Minecraft Script "Damage caused by" condition doesn't work

Tags: minecraft

I am trying to cancel all damage from hostile mobs when a variable for a player is true. Currently, It can cancel only attacks. When I tried to put the other types of damage it gives me the error `the damage does not have a past state`. I've struggled to find a solution to the syntax, but it makes things even worse.

Here is my code:

```
on damage of a player:
    if {mine.%victim%} is true:
        damage was caused by an attack, a projectile, an explosion, a potion, thorns or poison:
            attacker is not a player:
                cancel event
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like this :

```
on damage:
   if {mine.%victim%} is true:
      attacker is mob:
         cancel event
```